# C++11 std::function slower than virtual calls?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I am creating a mechanism which allows users to form arbitrary complex functions from basic building blocks using the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#C.2B.2B). This works fine functionality wise, but I don't like the fact that it involves a lot of virtual calls, particularly when the nesting depth becomes large. It worries me because the complex function may called often (>100.000 times).

To avoid this problem, I tried to turn the decorator scheme into a `std::function` once it was finished (cfr. `to_function()` in the SSCCE). All internal function calls are wired during construction of the `std::function`. I figured this would be faster to evaluate than the original decorator scheme because no virtual lookups need to be performed in the `std::function` version.

Alas, benchmarks prove me wrong: the decorator scheme is in fact faster than the `std::function` I built from it. So now I am left wondering why. Maybe my test setup is faulty since I only use two trivial basic functions, which means the vtable lookups may be cached?

The code I used is included below, unfortunately it is quite long.

---

## SSCCE

```cpp
// sscce.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

/**
 * Base class for Pipeline scheme (implemented via decorators)
 */
class Pipeline {
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> wrappee;
    Pipeline(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> wrap)
    :wrappee(std::move(wrap)){}
    Pipeline():wrappee(nullptr){}

public:
    typedef std::function<double(double)> FnSig;
    double operator()(double input) const{
        if(wrappee.get()) input=wrappee->operator()(input);
        return process(input);
    }

    virtual double process(double input) const=0;
    virtual ~Pipeline(){}

    // Returns a std::function which contains the entire Pipeline stack.
    virtual FnSig to_function() const=0;
};

/**
 * CRTP for to_function().
 */
template <class Derived>
class Pipeline_CRTP : public Pipeline{
protected:
    Pipeline_CRTP(const Pipeline_CRTP<Derived> &o):Pipeline(o){}
    Pipeline_CRTP(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> wrappee)
    :Pipeline(std::move(wrappee)){}
    Pipeline_CRTP():Pipeline(){};
public:
    typedef typename Pipeline::FnSig FnSig;

    FnSig to_function() const override{
        if(Pipeline::wrappee.get()!=nullptr){

            FnSig wrapfun = Pipeline::wrappee->to_function();
            FnSig processfun = std::bind(&Derived::process,
                static_cast<const Derived*>(this),
                std::placeholders::_1);
            FnSig fun = [=](double input){
                return processfun(wrapfun(input));
            };
            return std::move(fun);

        }else{

            FnSig processfun = std::bind(&Derived::process,
                static_cast<const Derived*>(this),
                std::placeholders::_1);
            FnSig fun = [=](double input){
                return processfun(input);
            };
            return std::move(fun);
        }

    }

    virtual ~Pipeline_CRTP(){}
};

/**
 * First concrete derived class: simple scaling.
 */
class Scale: public Pipeline_CRTP<Scale>{
private:
    double scale_;
public:
    Scale(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> wrap, double scale) // todo move
:Pipeline_CRTP<Scale>(std::move(wrap)),scale_(scale){}
    Scale(double scale):Pipeline_CRTP<Scale>(),scale_(scale){}

    double process(double input) const override{
        return input*scale_;
    }
};

/**
 * Second concrete derived class: offset.
 */
class Offset: public Pipeline_CRTP<Offset>{
private:
    double offset_;
public:
    Offset(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> wrap, double offset) // todo move
:Pipeline_CRTP<Offset>(std::move(wrap)),offset_(offset){}
    Offset(double offset):Pipeline_CRTP<Offset>(),offset_(offset){}

    double process(double input) const override{
        return input+offset_;
    }
};

int main(){

    // used to make a random function / arguments
    // to prevent gcc from being overly clever
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    auto randint = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,1),std::ref(generator));
    auto randdouble = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0),std::ref(generator));

    // make a complex Pipeline
    std::unique_ptr<Pipeline> pipe(new Scale(randdouble()));
    for(unsigned i=0;i<100;++i){
        if(randint()) pipe=std::move(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline>(new Scale(std::move(pipe),randdouble())));
        else pipe=std::move(std::unique_ptr<Pipeline>(new Offset(std::move(pipe),randdouble())));
    }

    // make a std::function from pipe
    Pipeline::FnSig fun(pipe->to_function());   

    double bla=0.0;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<100000; ++i){
#ifdef USE_FUNCTION
        // takes 110 ms on average
        bla+=fun(bla);
#else
        // takes 60 ms on average
        bla+=pipe->operator()(bla);
#endif
    }   
    std::cout << bla << std::endl;
}
```

---

## Benchmark

Using `pipe`:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 sscce.cpp -march=native -O3
sudo nice -3 /usr/bin/time ./a.out
-> 60 ms
```

Using `fun`:

```
g++ -DUSE_FUNCTION -std=gnu++11 sscce.cpp -march=native -O3
sudo nice -3 /usr/bin/time ./a.out
-> 110 ms
```

Comment: `std::function` is full of virtual lookups...

Comment: @KerrekSB Why is that? Aren't the virtual lookups removed by binding?

Comment: I would suggest you time the actual code, in code, instead of using the `time` command. Then do that many times, and average the times. Also, will the possible extra time really matter in the long run?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the results show the same trend when timing the actual code (this was just shorter). In this particular case the difference may not matter much, but I was so surprised by it that I decided to ask here. I would expect the `std::function` to be at least as fast as the nested calls ...

Comment: You're comparing 60ms and 110ms and think this is significant?

Comment: @MarcClaesen: How do you think `std::function` works? Since it can store *any* callable object, it must use some kind of dynamicism.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand that much, but it appears to involve at least as much dynamicism as the original approach which, in this test setup, involves 100 virtual calls.

Comment: @MarcClaesen I'm always sceptical about comparisons on run time in the range of a few milliseconds. But I reproduced your test with a longer loop and it confirms your measurements roughly (in fact on my machine it's more than twice as bad).

Comment: `Pipeline::process` is virtual in this code, so you haven't _replaced_ virtual calls with `std::function`, you've added to them, so now you have the overhead of virtual calls plus the overhead of `std::function`

Comment: Why are you using `std::move` on an rvalue?  A temporary `std::unique_ptr` is already an rvalue, you don't need to move it.

Comment: You also don't need to use `std::move(fun)` because returning local variables will use a move constructor if one exists. Using `std::move` probably disables the RVO.

Comment: And the `Pipeline_CRTP` copy constructor cannot work, its base class is not copyable. Remove that, and declare a defaulted move constructor instead. You could also define the default constructor as defaulted.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks for your remarks and suggestions. I thought the `process` calls in the `std::function` would no longer be virtual since I bind after a `static_cast` to the correct derived class ...

Comment: Well, ever wondered how `std::function` could do all the magic it does? Think about it, you can bind anything to it, be it a functor, a `std::bind` expression (well, that's a function object too in the end), a lambda (well, Ok, that too) or a function pointer. And this at runtime. So there is no doubt that there has to be something rather involved going on in a `std::function`, it's not just a function pointer. And whatever that is (most likely some kind of virtual dispatch), it takes its time.

Comment: @MarcClaesen, you cast `this` to the right type, but you call through `&Derived::process` which is a pointer to a virtual function, so calling it still does a virtual lookup.  My answer shows how to use `derived_this->Derived::process(input)` to avoid that virtual lookup, by statically calling `Derived::process(input)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Sebastian Redl's answer says, your "alternative" to virtual functions adds several layers of indirection through dynamically bound functions (either virtual, or through function pointers, depending on the `std::function` implementation) and then it still calls the virtual `Pipeline::process(double)` function anyway!

This modification makes it significantly faster, by removing one layer of `std::function` indirection and preventing the call to `Derived::process` being virtual:

```
FnSig to_function() const override {
    FnSig fun;
    auto derived_this = static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
    if (Pipeline::wrappee) {
        FnSig wrapfun = Pipeline::wrappee->to_function();
        fun = [=](double input){
            return derived_this->Derived::process(wrapfun(input));
        };
    } else {
        fun = [=](double input){
            return derived_this->Derived::process(input);
        };
    }
    return fun;
}
```

There's still more work being done here than in the virtual function version though.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement, it did indeed yield a significant speedup. I am wondering, though, why `std::bind(&Derived::process,static_cast<const Derived*>(this),std::placeholders::_1);` results in a virtual call? Doesn't the cast to the correct derived class (in which `process` is no longer virtual) circumvent the virtual call?

Comment: No, `&Derived::process` is still a pointer to a virtual function, any call through it is a virtual call. All you've cast is `this`, you haven't prevented calls through `&Derived::process` being virtual.

Comment: I see, thanks for all the information! I thought the result of the `bind` would be equivalent with your version, but this just goes to show that I have lots to learn :-)

Comment: To put it another way, the cast is equivalent to doing `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->process(input)` instead of `this->process(input)` i.e. it has no effect at all!

Answer (score 25):

You have `std::function`s binding lambdas that call `std::function`s that bind lamdbas that call `std::function`s that ...

Look at your `to_function`. It creates a lambda that calls two `std::function`s, and returns that lambda bound into another `std::function`. The compiler won't resolve *any* of these statically.

So in the end, you end with with just as many indirect calls as the virtual function solution, and that's if you get rid of the bound `processfun` and directly call it in the lambda. Otherwise you have twice as many.

If you want a speedup, you will have to create the entire pipeline in a way that can be statically resolved, and that means a lot more templates before you can finally erase the type into a single `std::function`.

Answer (score 9):

`std::function` is notoriously slow; type erasure and the resulting allocation play a part in this, also, with `gcc`, invocations are inlined/optimized badly. For this reason there exist a plethora of C++ "delegates" with which people attempt to resolve this problem. I ported one to Code Review:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11

But you can find plenty of others with Google, or write your own.

EDIT:

These days, look [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user1095108/generic/master/forwarder.hpp) for a fast delegate.

Comment: Excelent contribution. I was benchmarking the [Man or Boy test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Man_or_boy_test) with Objective-C (blocks) and C++ (lambdas) and C++ was really, really slow thanks to `std::function`. It got perfect with your code. ;)

Answer (score 6):

libstdc++ implementation of std::function works roughly as follows:

```
template<typename Signature>
struct Function
{
    Ptr functor;
    Ptr functor_manager;

    template<class Functor>
    Function(const Functor& f)
    {
        functor_manager = &FunctorManager<Functor>::manage;
        functor = new Functor(f);
    }

    Function(const Function& that)
    {
        functor = functor_manager(CLONE, that->functor);
    }

    R operator()(args) // Signature
    {
        return functor_manager(INVOKE, functor, args);
    }

    ~Function()
    {
        functor_manager(DESTROY, functor);
    }
}

template<class Functor>
struct FunctorManager
{
     static manage(int operation, Functor& f)
     {
         switch (operation)
         {
         case CLONE: call Functor copy constructor;
         case INVOKE: call Functor::operator();
         case DESTROY: call Functor destructor;
         }
     }
}
```

So although `std::function` doesn't know the exact type of the Functor object, it dispatches the important operations through a functor_manager function pointer that is a static function of a template instance that does know about the `Functor` type.

Each `std::function` instance will allocate on the heap its own owned copy of the functor object (unless it is not larger than a pointer, such as a function pointer, in which case it just holds the pointer as a subobject).

The important take away is that copying of `std::function` is expensive if the underlying functor object has an expensive copy constructor and/or takes lots of space (for example to hold bound parameters).

Comment: I don't know which implementation you're referring to but neither `boost::function` nor GCC's `std::function` uses virtual functions.  Some implementations might, but not all.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks, I misremembered completely - I have corrected my answer with an overview of the libstdc++ std::function architecture.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Interestingly the `FunctionManager<Functor>` object serves a purpose not unlike a vtable.  I'd be interested to know how much slower using virtual functions would have been.